# '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta' in Django

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Here I want to validate the start_time value in a range between greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to  video_duration,

models.py

```
class VideoBookmark(BaseModel, SoftDelete):    
    start_time = models.DurationField(default=timedelta())
    end_time = models.DurationField(default=timedelta())
```

serializers.py

```
class VideoBookmarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VideoBookmark
        fields = ('start_time', 'end_time',)

    def validate(self,data):
           ......

        video_duration = VideoDetails.objects.get(video=video_id).duration
        if not "00:00:00" <= data['start_time'] < video_duration:
            raise ValidationError('start time')

        return data
```

error

```
'<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

So, let me answer how to correctly refer to "greater than or equal to zero or less than video_duration"

Answer (score 0):

data['start_time'] is a time object expressed in microseconds. To compare it to zero (I take it that is what 00:00:00 is supposed to be) you can do:

```
if not 0 <= int(data['start_time'].total_seconds()/1000)
```

You are also comparing with video_duration so you should make sure this is also in microseconds.

Comment: Thanks, but this makes another mistake, and I finally got the answer with "total_seconds ()"         >>> "if not 0 <= data['start_time'].total_seconds() "

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. I've corrected the answer. This should work, you can edit the division if you need a different expression of time.